# Angular 5 - Table format is wrong (html page)

Tags: angular

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am having trouble formatting my table from an angular class using a service.

My table displays but they include commas (,) between every cells. I want to get ride of that.

in HTML

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Period</th>
        <th *ngFor="let m of types.Testing">
          {{m.colors}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <th></th>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Mytypes} from './model';
import { myserv } from './shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular 6';

    public types: Mytypes;

    constructor(public _service: myserv) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.types = this._service.GetData(true);
    }
}
```

Service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Mytypes, types} from './model';

@Injectable()

export class myserv{

  //sourc - not currently in use
  GetData(sourc: boolean): Mytypes{

    var view = new Mytypes();

    var main = new types();
    main.tests= [
      "--"
    ];
    main.colors= [
      "Blue" , "Red" , "Yellow"
    ];

    view.Testing = [
      main 
    ]

    return view;
}

  constructor() { }
}
```

Model

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class types{

  public tests: Array<string>;
  public colors: Array<string>;

  constructor() { }
}

@Injectable()
export class Mytypes{

  public Testing: Array<types>;
  constructor() { }
}
```

this currently displays as:

```
Blue,Red,Yellow
```

Expected to display as:

```
Blue   Red   Yellow
```

Issue live at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdame7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: may be your backend data have comma with colors string that is why it is printing

Comment: It is printing from this class: 

main.colors= [
     "Blue", "Red", "Yellow"
];

That is the only data that is reading from and trying to display atm.

Comment: your looping main.types and showing main.colors

Comment: yes because types has colors and other arrays in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are iterating over object array.

Try converting the object into array.

in component.ts

```
 this.mapped = Object.keys(this.types.Testing[0].colors).map(key => ({type: key, value: this.types.Testing[0].colors[key]}));
      console.log(this.mapped);
```

in your html

```
 <table>
      <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Period</th>
                <th *ngFor="let m of this.mapped">
                  {{m.value}}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <th></th>
            </tbody>
      </table>
```